# Restart Tomcat via command prompt: Access is denied

Tags: tomcat, command-line, windows-services, tomcat6, restart

I know that I can either use

```
sc start Tomcat6
```

or

```
net start Tomcat6
```

to start the tomcat service, however I get an error "Access is denied". How can I achieve restarting the tomcat service via command prompt and overcoming the error? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Windows Server 2008 or above (R2), you need to run your command prompt as administrator.  Create a desktop shortcut to "cmd" or c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe.  Then right-click the shortcut and "run as administrator".

Comment: +1 but you could just type cmd in the search bar and run as admin, save creating a shortcut :)

Comment: well i don't want to create a shortcut though. i want to do it via command line

Comment: The shortcut instructions (above) are only an example of one way of doing this. The point is mainly that you need to [run as an administrator]. As Bali C pointed out, you could do this from the search bar, or find Cmd in your start menu (and [right-click], run as admin) or if you are doing a scheduled process, make sure it is running as admin.